# Excel-VB read cell color

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wondering why my code is not reading the cell value correct.
The point is if excel marks a cell red and when a user pushes a validation button.
the macro gives a message depending on the cell color.

At the moment i'm testing this on "c4" but if i put it on red (255,0,0) it doesnt read it as "Red"

```
  Sub Validate()
        Dim xRng As Range
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = Sheets("TEMPLATE")
        Set xRng = Range("A2:N1000")

        If ws.Range("C4").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
            MsgBox "Found some errors, please review your template", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Validation"
        Else
            MsgBox "No direct errors found!", vbOKOnly + vbQuestion, "Validation"
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: try `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.red)` instead of `RGB(255, 0, 0)`

Comment: I was thinking the same thing as the code seems valid to me. But if i check it with color tool it says 255 0 0. Perhaps there is a marge of error on these. Il try every marge in a range if it worked i wil verify it!

Comment: Maybe the cell is red because of a conditional format. I changed the tags because I think this is pure VBA code at least I do not see anything regarding VB.NET

Comment: ah this is vba, thanks Storax for the edit anyway

Comment: I'm 100% sure that the cel colored RED are 255,0,0.. So it must be something in the code.

Comment: @Devcon Your suggestion gives the error "Invalid Qualifier"

Comment: Your code is working for me as long as I formatted the cell directly. But in case I use conditional formatting it will not work.

Comment: @Storax is right tried it myslef it doesn't work with conditional formatting, but it does work if i manually set the background color to red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cell was colored by a conditional format you need to check it like that

```
If ws.Range("C4").DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
    ' Your code here
Else
    ' Your code here
End If
```

Comment: Thank, it as in deed by conditional formatting! Good to know it has to be called with DisplayFormat. Thanks for this!